# How can I make SQLite tell my application when the database file has changed?

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm planning to make an application that has to save data in an SQLite database. Is there some way to make SQLite call a callback function when it has altered the database file?

I want to know when the database file has changed so I can make a new [version](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/auto-save.html) of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably interested in writing an [Rollback / Commit Hook](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/commit_hook.html). These are fairly well documented. You also have the option of writing a [Update Hook](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html) as well, depending on your needs. I think you are best off using a commit hook; so that when the changes have been committed to the database, you can create a version.